# How to Order an SQL Query by Left Join Result

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a SQL query with a left join that works just fine. However, I'm having difficulties ordering the results.

The query looks like this:

```
SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS wp_posts.ID FROM wp_posts INNER JOIN wp_postmeta ON ( wp_posts.ID = wp_postmeta.post_id ) LEFT OUTER JOIN wp_posts recent ON recent.post_parent = wp_posts.ID AND recent.post_type = 'ticket_reply' AND recent.post_author = wp_posts.post_author WHERE 1=1 AND ( ( wp_postmeta.meta_key = '_wpas_status' AND CAST(wp_postmeta.meta_value AS CHAR) = 'open' ) ) AND wp_posts.post_type = 'ticket' GROUP BY wp_posts.ID ORDER BY CASE WHEN recent.post_parent IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END, recent.post_date DESC, wp_posts.post_date DESC LIMIT 0, 20
```

The query works fine and is correctly sorted date-wise.

However, the entries that aren't in the intersection (that is, posts of the `ticket` type that have no `ticket_reply` children) are displayed last. I need those to be displayed first, and then to display the rest by date as seen in the original query.

I'm not sure if this request is clear enough. If not please let me know what clarification is needed and I'll do my best to clarify.

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS wp_posts.ID 
FROM wp_posts 
LEFT OUTER JOIN wp_posts recent 
   ON recent.post_parent = wp_posts.ID AND 
      recent.post_type = 'ticket_reply' AND 
      recent.post_author = wp_posts.post_author 
WHERE 1=1 AND wp_posts.post_type = 'ticket' 
GROUP BY wp_posts.ID 
ORDER BY CASE WHEN recent.post_parent IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END,
         recent.post_date ASC, 
         wp_posts.post_date DESC 
LIMIT 0, 20
```

This predicate `recent.post_parent IS NULL` identifies unmatched records. The `CASE` expression return a `0` value for these records and `1` for the rest of the records. Hence, this way unmatched records will be displayed first, followed by the rest of the records.

Comment: Unfortunately, this doesn't change the order. However, I realize that I might have left an important piece of information our of the original query: there was a first inner join added. Maybe this changes the `ORDER BY` behavior.

I have edited the original SQL query.

Comment: @Julien Can you post some sample data so that we will be able to reproduce the issue?

Comment: I'm not sure exactly what's the best data sample to share. Here is a dump of my wp_posts table. It comes from my dev environment so there might be a stupid thing or two in it. http://jmp.sh/AZyzf09

The idea is to have the tickets without a reply first ("My Third Ticket" and "My First Ticket") and then "My Second Ticket" which has a reply.

Comment: @Julien As far as I can see, "My Second Ticket" has `recent.post_parent` equal to `NULL`. How come this ticket has a reply?

Comment: All tickets (`post_type='ticket'`) have `post_parent` set to `0`. All ticket replies (`post_type='ticket_reply'`) have `post_parent` set to the `ID` of the ticket they belong to.

Because "My Second Ticket" is a `post_type='ticket'` its `post_parent` is `0`. This ticket has a reply and the reply has its `post_parent` set to `137`, which is "My Second Ticket"'s post `ID`.

Does that answer your question? I'm not entirely sure I understood it correctly.

Comment: @Julien Why isn't the query returning this reply? This condition `recent.post_parent = wp_posts.ID` isn't successful for any of the records returned by the query.

Comment: I think I might be better off starting from the beginning again as my original query maybe isn't what it should be.

The idea is to sort tickets in the following order: tickets with no reply (`tiket_reply`) at the top, then ticket with replies where the last reply `post_author` !== ticket `post_author`, and finally tickets with replies where last reply `post_author` === ticket `post_author`.

Does the initial query seem right for this scenario or not at all?